# Node.js Express app.get: Browser want to open the link

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, pug

I have the following problem.
In my node.js application, the user clicks on link which send it by get to my app.js. The Link is a filename. In my app.js I can read the param, but the browser still tries to open the file in the browser

```
app.get('/files/:file', function(req, res) {
    console.log('Would handle ' + req.params.file);
});
```

So what I have to do to stop the browser opening the link?

Comment: Probably your browser is trying to download that file by default. Have you tried adding a content type to your response? `res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain'); res.send();`

Comment: Yes, then I get blank page, but I won't to stay on my current page.

Comment: Ah, already, now I get it. Just set the content type according to your download file!

Comment: Ah sorry, I think you misunderstood what I want. :)
I don't want to download the file I clicked, I just want to send it to my app.js. On the website there should happen nothing.

Comment: What do you mean? If you send a request to your server, the server has to respond.

Comment: Yes the server gets the filename and runs a script on the server. The link is like a play button, you click on it and the server do something. In my case a movie on a raspberry pi. :)

Comment: Let me see if I'm understand your question properly.  You have essentially a list of files on your server.  An end user, can click on a link on this page (somesite.com/files) and the link is something like (i.e., somesite.com/files/thisfile).  After he clicks on that link, what is he expecting to see?  The same somesite.com/files page?  Is he supposed to download the file?

Comment: This is all very confusing. You are very unclear about your goal.

Comment: Why can't you just use res.redirect('back') after your console.log?

Comment: yeah res.redirect('back') worked for me! :D
Thank you very much. Sorry but I just started with node.js

Comment: Use javascript and AJAX in order to make calls to server without redirects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comment above.  You can use:

```
app.get('/files/:file', function(req, res) {
    console.log('Would handle ' + req.params.file);
    res.redirect('back');
});
```

You can read more information about this on the [Express - api reference](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.redirect) page.  The res.redirect('back') will redirect to the referring page; if there is no referring page, it will default to '/'.  Hope this information helps.